# Deleting Android Calendar when app is uninstalled

Tags: android, android-calendar

I've been writing an app that has Calendar support using the Android Calendar Provider. I want  my app updates the calendar I already create with new events. 
Right now I can create a Calendar and add Events to it. The problem I'm facing is that I **can't delete the calendar when the app is uninstalled**. 
I read about the android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED broadcast, but I can't catch my own broadcast. The Calendar is created Locally, is not synced. Also, I'm writing the app with support to API 10.

Comment: I am looking at the issue too but I couldnot find a way to delete this. Calendar entries are not deleted from the settings using clear application data.

Comment: That is not *your* calendar. It is the *user's* calendar, and so it remains. This is no different than putting files on external storage in a public directory (e.g., `Environment.DIRECTORY_PHOTOS`).

Comment: @CommonsWare, I'm not adding events to an existing calendar. But, are you suggesting that is not possible because the calendar that I created with my app starts belonging to the user.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am inserting calendar entries from my app to the google calendar(I am asking user to select the email address for which to add) and insertion works. But on logout of the the user from my app I need to delete the entries from google calendar. I searched but tried deleting but it was not successful. I came to a conclusion that it is not allowed. Am I right??

Comment: "But, are you suggesting that is not possible because the calendar that I created with my app starts belonging to the user" -- yes. Some things that you create (e.g., files on internal storage) belong to your app. Some things that you create (e.g., files in public external storage directories) really belong to the user. Only those things belonging to your app, and not the user, get removed at uninstall time.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with a completely client side solution. An app can not listen for it's own uninstall broadcast.

I know this is not what you're looking for and is much more work, but just for fun...if you REALLY need this functionality, you could do something like:

1. In your app, request OAuth access to edit a user's Google calendar for a particular account. Store the access/refresh token on the server side.
2. Have your app ping your server occasionally, or use Push on the server side to ping your app and see if it's still installed.
3. If you find that the app is not installed, have your server edit the user's Google Calendar to remove events created by your app. To be nice, revoke your own OAuth access and delete any tokens or otherwise user-related information you've stored on the server side.